# Add single link item to menu without user needing to log in again

Tags: cartthrob, ee5, menu

I'm having trouble adding a link to CartThrob Order Manager into a control panel menu using Menu Manager.

The plugin doesn't offer a pre-ser menu option, so I need to do this with a single link, as I understand it.  the problem is that the URL for the specific page seems to have a code in the URL that specifically identifies me as a user.  This menu needs to work for anyone logged in with the appropriate permissions.  If I remove the bit in the URl that's specific to me (&S=...) any user clikcing the menu item si required to log in again, even if they are already logged in and have permissions to view that page.

Am I missing something obvious?

Cheers,

Crac

PS. Just to clarify version numbers: EE 5.3.0, CT Pro 4.6.1, CT OM 4.6.1 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible - I have a similar link on one of my sites that uses CT.

All you need to do is create a single link using this for the URL

`cp/addons/settings/cartthrob_order_manager`

HTH

PS - Usually helpful to include **version numbers** in questions like this, as answers will sometimes vary between versions of EE and add-on (such as CT in this case).

Comment: Thank you, that works - is there a simple explanation why this doesn;t require you to log in and the full url (https://www.[domain].co.uk/admin.php?/cp/addons/settings/cartthrob_order_manager) does?  Just curious ...

Comment: I don't know for sure - but I suspect it might be simply to do with how EE is processing the link - the relative URL perhaps is used to adjust current session, while if you put in a full url maybe EE starts up a new browser session when you follow the link?  Or something else... :)